# referencing cell based on specific data in excel

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to get the cell address (column number and Row number) based on the data it has.

Example: Cell A1 has value 8 and column B has number 1 to 100 in random order (no value repeating twice).  I want to know which cell in column B has the same value as cell A1 and enter that value in cell A2.

Answer (score 0):

=match(a1,b:b,0) will return row of the match from cell A1

Comment: Written iPad will expand on this later to give full explanation and alternatives